# Bogo sort on NDTM

Tags: sorting, nondeterminism

As we know on NDTM all the **possible solutions** for a given problem **is verified** the similar kind of work is done in bogo sort sequentially.

*So in future if an NDTM will be there. can we say it will be using bogo sort for sorting?*

Answer (score 2):

Sure, bogosort is efficient on a nondeterministic Turing machine.

But there is no known way to implement a nondeterministic Turing machine so the answer to any question of the form "If we have a physical nondeterministic, will it do X?$ is the same as "If I become pope, will X happen?" The answer is almost certainly "yes" because false implies anything.